# What happened to "dividing the Shema"?

Tags: tefilla, shema, bircas-krias-shema

The Mishnah in Talmud Bavli [Megilah 23b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=23b&format=pdf) mentions something called פורס על שמע.

Rash"i explains that the term פורס means "to divide". the idea, here, is that if there is a minyan of people who arrived in shul after the congregation has said the *Shema*, one person says *Kaddish*, *Barchu* and the 1st bracha of the *Shema* (*Yotzer Hame'orot*).

(FYI - Tosfot cites other sources regarding how many others are required for someone to do this action.)

Is this action done by anyone, currently? If not, approximately when and why was this abolished?

Comment: I have seen ppl who have came late to shul and there were no more minyanim

Comment: Rema (OC 69:1) says we no longer say *Birkat Yotzer*, just *Kaddish* and *Barchu*.